# Disable the timestamps that appear in the debugger console when calling NSLog in XCode 9

Tags: debugging, logging, swift3, xcode9, console.log

How to disable or hide the time stamp in the debugger console while calling NSLog().

```
/** LOG to see AFF_FLOW*/
func showLog(classname:String , tagName:String){

    NSLog("APP_FLOW -- \(classname)--> \(tagName)")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short term solution** using **print()**.

```
/* LOG to see AFF_FLOW*/
func showLog(classname:String , tagName:AnyObject){

    print("APP_FLOW -- \(classname)--> \(tagName) \n")

}
```